# Ubuntu 16.04 no display at all with caps lock light blinking

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

I have dual boot system with ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10.

Everything was working fine, last night I was using ubuntu and I shutdown the system, while it was shutting down I closed the lid.

Now when I start system there is no display at all with caps lock light blinking.
I tried to search for solution, mostly say that its **kernel panic**, but couldn't find any solution.

> THERE IS NO DISPLAY AT ALL, AND I AM NOT EVEN ABLE TO GO MENU BOOT
>   MENU.

Is there any solution, what should I do?

Comment: Can you press e from grub boot menu, remove splash and quiet from kernel boot line and press F10 to start. Then you will be able to see the kernel panic, a photo then can be useful.

Comment: @olivierb2 didn't get it, there is no display at all. kindly can you tell me step by step like force shut and than start and than ...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say how to display grub : https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time Basically maintaining shift or esc in UEFI.

Comment: I assume you have at least the BIOS screen, right ?